# Automatically detect blips (noise spikes, abrupt endings, etc) in music files

Tags: audio, music, audio-streaming

Is there anything out there that will scan a music file and report on whether or not there are problems with blips in the audio? These blips would essentially be any noise that would cause you to flinch, cringe, wake up, etc... while listening to the music. It would be great if it also detected abrupt endings to songs (which are sometimes intentionally but often not).

I'm trying to get some of my music collection ready for a playlist and don't want any annoying surprises!

(The audio-streaming tag is because I imagine that this would be applicable to downloads of streamed music.)

Comment: Years ago, there was a tool called [MP3Shield](http://download.cnet.com/MP3-Shield/3000-2170_4-47270.html) which you could point to a folder of music files and it would scan them to check for corrupt/fake/incomplete songs. It was pretty good, but was not foolproof and would miss one here or there or give the occasional false-positive. (You could submit files for them to fix their scanning engine, but of course, it has long since been discontinued.) I don’t *think* it could detect abnormalities like blips or spikes. (Hmm, cnet seems to have the second last version, 2.4.2; my copy says 2.4.3.)